# How to find the wear rate of materials in the net?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, data

Are there any free online databases where I can access data for the wear rates of materials? I tried using CES EduPack, but I'm having no luck.

Maybe other free and open databases are also existing on the net? Where and how could I find the wear rate in them?

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. Do you have any particular material of interest?

Comment: Wear rate will depend heavily on application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check out [tribology](http://www.tribology-abc.com/abc/adhesion.htm). There is such thing as specific wear rate, k, for example, which is given for a pair of materials in dynamic contact. Say steel over steel has very low coefficient, even better than PTFE over steel, for example.